# Language Services: find Node at position

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm using Typescript Language Services.

I need to find a ts.Node having just a ts.SourceFile instance and an absolute position (number) of interest as input parameters.

Moreover, I need to cater cases when the token of interest is an `else` keyword for example, or an opening brace `{`, or located inside an `if` condition.

Does anyone know if such a function already exists in the Language Services?

**UPD**: I managed to find function `getTouchingToken` (that is presumably does what I need) somewhere in Typescript source code, but I don't see it being exported. Any clues how to reuse it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I managed to find function getTouchingToken (that is presumably does what I need) somewhere in Typescript source code, but I don't see it being exported. Any clues how to reuse it

I use `ts.getTokenAtPosition` e.g. to provide the quickfix feature in [alm tools for TypeScript](https://github.com/alm-tools/alm)

[image]

Comment: Seems like this thing is accessible via `(ts as any).getTokenAtPosition`, however this is close to a hack. Am I missing something in my typings?

Comment: [NTypeScript](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ntypescript) is now dead and its replacement appears to be [Bring your own TypeScript](https://github.com/basarat/byots) (also by basarat).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`tsutils`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsutils) which includes [`getTokenAtPosition`](https://github.com/ajafff/tsutils/blob/11da31212257466a2164ca978b782139ca3f38f5/util/util.ts#L151).

This is better than relying on internal TypeScript API that might break any time.